# Google +1 Button on mobile version of site

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I'm trying to add a Google +1 button to my site.  I'm using rails, so I have two views from the same URL - one is for mobile and one not for mobile.  I'm trying to add the Google +1 button on the mobile view, and obviously when someone hits it from a browser it will go to the non-mobile page.

Unfortunately, the +1 button will not render on the mobile view.  It is fine on the web view.  According to Google's +1 docs/faq's:

*"Will users on mobile browsers see the +1 button?
We are not including the +1 button on mobile search results at this time. However, users may be able to see any +1 buttons you have added to your web pages."*

Well..I don't care about the Google search results, I only care about my mobile view.  Any ideas?

Comment: Link to your page that isn't working.

Comment: unfortunately it is just in dev now.  I followed the instructions here though: ( http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html )   and the +1 icon will appear in my desktop browser as expected, but it won't render in on my mobile phone.

Comment: @nelsonenzo Google now supports mobile +1 buttons. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google supports mobile +1 buttons now.

> *Does the +1 button appear when my site is viewed in mobile browsers?*
>   Yes! We've added support for iOS 4.0+ and Android 2.1+, so once you
>   add the +1 button code to your site, the button will be automatically
>   visible on pages viewed using these browsers.
>
> *Does the +1 button appear in search results on mobile browsers?*
>   No, the +1 button is not yet supported for mobile search results.
>
> *I can't see inline annotations on my mobile browser. What up?*
>   Currently, we don't support inline annotations in mobile browsers.

[Source: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1140194]